# VS SetUp set expiry date without using db

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

I need to create a msi file  which would be expire after say 45 days using VS setup Project.
How can i implement this without using the database.The user wont be able to change or update any settings of expiry.

Comment: I think the easiest and cheapest way to implement this using a license server. I do not know any secure way which implements this from an installer or licensing technology. However HASP can be a solution if you really do not want to implement a license server.

Comment: You can implement a before install action that checks against a hardcoded date. Not safe but good enough for most situations.

Comment: Since the user can change the date time settings of OS , your demo becomes an infinite demo. I think it is not a good reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in Visual Studio Setup Project to do so.

Instead you can read the values from registry / other secure source on Application Start

Here is a code snippet on how to do it without DB

[Code Snippet: TrialTimeManager class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/001bdbdd-a0c9-4356-b32c-65c819f26a6b/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by Visual Studio. You can try choosing one of the following solutions:

1. Use a commercial setup authoring tool which supports product licensing. It's pretty painless, but it's expensive.
2. Write your own licensing mechanism and implement it in your application.
3. Try to find a dedicated solution which costs less than a commercial setup authoring tool.